# Creating an email in Java

Tags: java, email, outlook

I would like to "create" an email using Java.

Here's what I mean:

Based on information I already have, I would like to make an email message open in Microsoft Outlook with the fields To, CC, Subject, Message Body, and attachments already populated (all now stored as strings, the directories for attachments are stored as strings as well).

The message needs to open in Outlook for the user to verify the contents and give the opportunity for adding more CC, slight adjustments to subject and message body.

From what I gather, it seems that the "best" way of achieving this is first creating a file on disk that Outlook can read, which contains my message, then opening it with outlook using something similar to the code below.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("OUTLOOK Directory + CMD switches for opening files");
```

1. Ideally, I would like to use a simple framework for simply creating such a file using the strings I already have for the different fields (or achieving the same thing through a a non-simple framework).
2. If there's no "good" way of achieving the above, I'd settle for a method of just attaching my attachment file to a given Outlook template (.oft) file.

(3. I'll resort to my current solution of simply having the template open in Outlook, the attachment in Explorer, and prompt the user to drag the file into Outlook.)

I've looked at HSMF in Apache POI (I'm Apache POI for other parts of my program), but it appears to be rather experimental at this point, and I've been unable to find much documentation for it.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to look?

Comment: Java Mail API could be a good starting point. Take a look https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home

Comment: +1 for JavaMail. Assemble a MimeMessage then write it to a *.eml (or *.msg) file with the writeTo(OutputStream) method.

Comment: Thank you, I took a look at Javamail, but after a few hours of not finding a way to create a working solution, I simply decided that my option 3. would have to suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#mail-java.net.URI-) API with the [URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) constructor that will quote legal characters.  This example code will open your default mail client with the headers populated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URI msg = new URI("mailto", "you@foo.com&cc=team@bar.com&subject=How to create email in Java?body=Use JavaMail.", (String) null);
    Desktop.getDesktop().mail(msg);
}
```

The only limitation is that there is an [upper limit](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830473) to the length of the URI that the O/S can handle.  On windows, the 'start' command also understands the syntax which is explained in [RFC 2368](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt).