# Preview an email before sending

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, jakarta-mail

I created an Email html form in java web application I need to add an feature for preview an HTML email before sending. I already [read this][1]
  [1]: [Preview an email in default mail client before sending with Java and MimeMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449712/preview-an-email-in-default-mail-client-before-sending-with-java-and-mimemessage) but it didn't help me, I need to know what are other library of java that i used to get this type of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

From your initial question it is a bit unclear for me what you want to achieve and what you already have done (and what requirements do you have).

If your user needs to create a mail in web browser and later preview it there, you can just add another html component which will render user's input as html. You could try to use html WYSIWYG editor like [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/), they usually have built in preview. So user finishes his edit, previews that message in the editor and then you send html source text of the message to your servlet where JavaMail processes it.

If you have a native Java Swing application, then you can use a component, which can handle such content like JEditorPane. Do not forget to set proper content type for it (text/html).

If you are using JavaFX application, then you could try to use embedded browser. More information and examples can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm).

In any case you just need to get a component which can handle your html content, put user's html into it and show it when user requests a preview.

Comment: I  am making an mail merge system similar to microsoft mail merge for an user so i need to preview a mail of many people before sending, can you suggest me the best way to implement this.

Comment: Is your application web-based where user previews message in a browser or standalone?

Comment: Its an java web application.

Comment: The easiest way is to use WYSIWYG editor at your html page, but you need to find a way how to preview mail attachments. And after previewing you can send email using JavaMail or any other library.