# How do I open the default mail client along with an attachment in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mailto

How do I open the default mail client along with an attachment in Java?

The attachment files can be multiple.

The code must be OS agnostic or at least should be capable to run on Windows OS & Mac OS.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help.

Comment: Same issue as: [Preview an email in default mail client before sending with Java and MimeMessage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449712/preview-an-email-in-default-mail-client-before-sending-with-java-and-mimemessage)